# format datetimeinput in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a booking site and I want the booking to be permanent only by hours (I don't want minutes) an example of John booked from 8 to 10 o'clock
And I don't want 8:10 to 10: 30 pm
Can I remove the minutes from DateTimeInput format that the user cannot choose them and selects only the hour
look at the picture here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAw44.jpg)

Or any other way to do this

Comment: _Or any other way to do this_ Make your own simple dropdown selection box that only allows the user to choose an hour?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that takes input in type time:
class timeInput(forms.timeInput):
input_type = 'time'

and use this inside your booking form input like this:

bookingTime=forms.TimeField(widget=timeInput(attrs={step:'3600'})
(here the attribute u wanna give is in hours, so 1hr=3600secs u can take as this in the step attribute)